# dd fail to write to tmpfs

Tags: linux, dd, tmpfs

I'd like to measure tmpfs performance by using dd. But it fail, like below:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/128M bs=4M count=32 oflag=direct  
dd: failed to open ‘/tmp/128M’: Invalid argument
```

Any help?

Comment: What does "file /tmp/128M" give you? looks like the file do not exist. Maybe you do not have permissions? Try sudo

Answer (score 14):

tmpfs does not support direct I/O and returns -EINVAL.

Answer (score 5):

Vasily Tarasov solution worked with NFS too.
I had:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=TEST.200GB iflag=direct bs=1M count=204800
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/urandom’: Invalid argument
```

then I have removed **iflag=direct** and it worked